# Translations Service

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm looking for a solution/idea to dynamically change the translation value of each key in Sparatcus translations files outside the code. I don't want only to create a file and override the I18nModule config, I'm looking for some kind of service/API like Lokalize API to be able to change the translation values outside the code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internationalisation features are prepared for this. Although we do not have a service at hand for the localised labels, Spartacus is prepared for this. You can read more about this at https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/i18n/#lazy-loading. You can configure `loadPath` to an API endpoint, including the variable language (`lng`) and namespace (`ns`).

```
imports: [
  B2cStorefrontModule.withConfig({
    i18n: {
        backend: {
            loadPath: 'assets/i18n-assets/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
            // crossOrigin: true (use this option when i18n assets come from a different domain)
        },
        chunks: translationChunksConfig
    }
  })
];
```