# how to have dynamic translation in spartacus?

Tags: internationalization, spartacus-storefront

I am using Spartacus 4.2 . I want to serve translations using my own custom endpoint. I am making the api call using APP_INITIALIZER token. My question is how will I set the result in provideConfig(). Or is there any other approach to serve translations dynamically?
I want to update mytranslationsEN when I have response from the api.

**spartacus-configuration.module.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { translationChunksConfig, translations } from '@spartacus/assets';
import {
 FeaturesConfig,
 I18nConfig,
 OccConfig,
 provideConfig,
 SiteContextConfig,
 TranslationResources,
 } from '@spartacus/core';
import {
 defaultCmsContentProviders,
 layoutConfig,
 mediaConfig,
} from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { mytranslationsfr } from 'src/assets/translations/fr/index.fr';

export let mytranslationsEN: TranslationResources = {}; 



function initializeAppFactory(httpClient: HttpClient): () => Observable<any> {
  return () => httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/translations')
   .pipe(
     tap(translations => { 
      mytranslationsEN= {
                product:{...translations}
              };
     })
    
    );
  }



 @NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [],
 providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
    deps: [HttpClient],
    multi: true,
  },
 provideConfig(layoutConfig),
 provideConfig(mediaConfig),
 ...defaultCmsContentProviders,
 provideConfig(<OccConfig>{
  backend: {
    occ: {
      baseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002',
    },
  },
}),
provideConfig(<SiteContextConfig>{
  context: {
    urlParameters: ['baseSite', 'language', 'currency'],
    baseSite: ['apparel-uk-spa'],
  },
}),
provideConfig(<SiteContextConfig>{
  context: {
    currency: ['GBP'],
    language: ['en'],
  },
}),
provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
  i18n: {
    resources: translations,
    chunks: translationChunksConfig,
    fallbackLang: 'en',
  },
}),
provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
  i18n: {
    resources: {
      en: mytranslationsEN ,
      fr: mytranslationsfr,
    },
    fallbackLang: 'en',
  },
}),
provideConfig(<FeaturesConfig>{
  features: {
    level: '4.2',
    },
  }),
 ],
})
export class SpartacusConfigurationModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a similar situation with dynamically loading translations has been discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65224726/12566149

Comment: In the provided solution,  JSON was provided from the  asset folder. But I am ttrying to fetch the translations from custom endpoint .

Comment: It is suggested that the `loadPath` can be replaced by an API endpoint. Is this not the case in practice?

Comment: I tried and it's working fine . But it replaces all the translations even if the chunk is not provided . I want to serve translations dynamically for few chunks only . I am doing like this . 
    `provideConfig(<I18nConfig>{
      i18n: {
        backend: {
          loadPath: 'http://localhost:3000/translations/{{lng}}/{{ns}}',
          crossOrigin: true,
        },
        chunks: {
          product: ['productDetails', 'productSummary', 'TabPanelContainer'],
        },
        fallbackLang: 'en',
      },
    }),`